# How to prevent pane overlapping in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

for my school project I am trying to make Classdiagrams graphical editor in JavaFX.
I have one rootpane (Pane) and by iterating through input parser I print graphical objects.
Every graphical object is child of Pane which holds elements (rect,text,line...) and that Pane with elements is child node of Rootpane (Pane). So Rootpane (Pane) has few childs of Pane.
Problem is, that after creating the Panes with graphical elements they do make some overlay around every Pane and I cannot drag other Panes.
I need to explicitly set Pane dimensions for example to be clipped by main Rectangle.
But this is not possible. Only way to do is make child nodes StackPane instead of Pane but my whole implementation now stands on absoulete positioning so It would be to rework whole project.
Does anyone know, by which command Can I set bounds to every Pane node not to overlay other nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not make the elements a Pane. Instead I would use a Group node. And you can set a clipping path for every node (the group in your case), so I do not quite understand what your problem is.

Comment: This was a real solution! Thanks. Instead of new Pane() I did new Group() and everythink works. Thank you!